# Does Python provide ways to run the same unit test with multiple test inputs?

Tags: python, unit-testing

With C# and NUnit, there exists the [TestCase attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6.4) and the T[estCaseSource attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.4), both of which allows unit tests to be parameterized, so that the same "test" can be used multiple times with different input. This reduces code duplication while maintaining readability.

Does something similar exist for Python?

EDIT:
@Dunes mentioned [subtests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#subtests), which I should have included as part of this question. Unfortunately, it is a 3.4 only functionality, and I'm looking to support 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: Are you running python 3.4? If so, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#subtests

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. I'm trying to be compatible for 3.4 and 2.7 unfortunately, but I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#subtests). However, this is only available as of Python 3.4.

There is [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2), though. It provides a backport of the latest features of unittest in Python 3.4 (including `subTest`). `unittest2` is tested to run on Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and pypy.

Answer (score 0):

Several libraries will allow you to do this. For example, the py.test example is as follows:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])

def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

This is from the [py.test documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html).